# Jenkins server is running slow

Tags: jenkins

My Jenkins server is so slow. Java takes 120% or CPU. How can I give Jenkins more memory access.

Of what steps can I take to improve the load time for Jenkins

Comment: We also have such problem  and it happens periodically. Honestly speaking it is difficult to identify the reason. Still searching ...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can allocate more memory and swap heap sizes using the following commands.

These can be set in the job configuration or Jenkins -> Manage -> Configure

> -Xmx512m
>   -XX:MaxPermSize=128m

Comment: I am unable to see Configure option in manage jenkins, my Jenkins version was 2.426. Can you suggest me a version of jenkins which is faster and can be install in AWS ec2 instance.

Answer (score 9):

*If* Java memory is causing the problem, then you can add more heap via the `-Xmx` option, as suggested in Priyam's answer. By default, JVM limits heap to 25% of your available RAM.

**More heap has a caveat**, though: if you add heap in the range of several GB, then the default JVM garbage collection algorithm will periodically impose *stop-the-world* breaks in the range of several seconds. You then need to switch to a custom garbage collection algorithm (like, CMS) and then carefully tune its parameters.

If adding more heap does not fix your problem, then you need to dig deeper. There's a **plethora of possible root causes for a slow master** -- from JVM memory and garbage collection settings to plugin issues, on top of the usual CPU/disk/IO-dimensioning issues.

Answer (score 0):

Manage Jenkins -> Configure System - > Robot Framework
Deselect checkbox as -> [Display "Robot Results" column in the job list view ]

[Please look here for detailed screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aTbfH.png)