# Server slows down when jenkins is building

Tags: jenkins

I noticed that when jenkins is building my server takes time to process requests.

I have like 10 projects running on my server but when jenkins starts building 2 projects everything just slow down, server response go from 100ms up to 14+ seconds. I upgraded the SSD to a faster one and improved the situation but still crazy slow when building.

Does anyone knows what could be causing this issue or how I can debug where the bottleneck is?

Comment: ....and do you have any question about this?

Comment: Have you run a system check on memory cpu network etc on the machine when its building? I would start with that but more importantly is your build server different from where its deployed as well? My guess is during build its consuming tons of memory or cpu cycles. Whats the server specs? Does it only happen one 2 concurrent builds or on any number of builds?

Comment: @EugeneDW My server has 4 vCPUs and 16GB RAM and a Premium SSD on AZURE, when building RAM and CPU goes a little higher but don't pass 50%. Is only one server.

Comment: Ok thats odd, whats the current heap size at?

Comment: I updated jenkins and it works better but still have some issues, @EugeneDW how I can find the heap size? In my jenkins.xml I see the params
MAXOPENFILES=8192 and JAVA_ARGS="-Djava.awt.headless=true"

Comment: Have a look at this solution https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39057563/jenkins-server-is-running-slow